# MultiselectListpreference in android

Tags: android, preference

I am working with ICS android and using the MultiSlectListPreference.
Please can anyone tell me how do I get the state of the check box that is there in the dialog. 
I just want to read the state of the check box.(true/false)

thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
pref.getBoolean(<key>, <default value>);
```

Where *key* is specified in your XML file by android:key, and *default* value is well, the default value.